# PHP - Display time in dropdown

Tags: php, time

I'd like some help please. I'm having this dropdown menu

```
<select name="schedule_time">
    <option value="00:00:00">00:00:00</option>
    <option value="00:30:00">00:30:00</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">01:00:00</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">01:30:00</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">02:00:00</option>
    <option value="02:30:00">02:30:00</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">03:00:00</option>
    <option value="03:30:00">03:30:00:00</option>
    <option value="04:00:00">04:00:00</option>
    <option value="04:30:00">04:30:00</option>
    <option value="05:00:00">05:00:00</option>
    <option value="05:30:00">05:30:00</option>
    <option value="06:00:00">06:00:00</option>
    <option value="06:30:00">06:30:00</option>
    <option value="07:00:00">07:00:00</option>
    <option value="07:30:00">07:30:00</option>
    <option value="08:00:00">08:00:00</option>
    <option value="08:30:00">08:30:00</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
    <option value="09:30:00">09:30:00</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
    <option value="10:30:00">10:30:00</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
    <option value="11:30:00">11:30:00</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
    <option value="12:30:00">12:30:00</option>
    <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
    <option value="13:30:00">13:30:00</option>
    <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option>
    <option value="14:30:00">14:30:00</option>
    <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option>
    <option value="15:30:00">15:30:00</option>
    <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option>
    <option value="16:30:00">16:30:00</option>
    <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option>
    <option value="17:30:00">17:30:00</option>
    <option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option>
    <option value="18:30:00">18:30:00</option>
    <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
    <option value="19:30:00">19:30:00</option>
    <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
    <option value="20:30:00">20:30:00</option>
    <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
    <option value="21:30:00">21:30:00</option>
    <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option>
    <option value="22:30:00">22:30:00</option>
    <option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option>
    <option value="23:30:00">23:30:00</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to make it a little bit more dynamic, instead of having this huge html ?

Something like this

```
<?php foreach (date('H:i:s') as $time): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $time; ?>"><?php echo $time; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you have two drop downs - 1 for hour and 1 for month, seconds are constant in your case - 0

Comment: This is what I already have. one for date and one for time, like you said

Comment: I prefer to split hours and minutes in time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use while loop to make it,

```
<?php
    $start = "00:00"; //you can write here 00:00:00 but not need to it
    $end = "23:30";

    $tStart = strtotime($start);
    $tEnd = strtotime($end);
    $tNow = $tStart;
    echo '<select name="schedule_time">';
    while($tNow <= $tEnd){
        echo '<option value="'.date("H:i:s",$tNow).'">'.date("H:i:s",$tNow).'</option>';
        $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Best and simplest method:

```
<select>
<?php 
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++)
{
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30)
    { 
        $time = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':00';
        echo '<option value= "'.$time.'">'.$time.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can try this code, you can take whatever range $start and $end variable .

```
  <?php
$start = "12:00:00";
$end = "24:00:00";

$tStart = strtotime($start);
$tEnd = strtotime($end);
$tNow = $tStart;
?>
<select name="schedule_time">
<?php
while($tNow <= $tEnd){ ?>

    <option value="<?php  echo date("H:i:s",$tNow); ?>"> <?php echo date("H:i:s",$tNow);?></option>
    <?php

  $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
 <?php 
        $start = '00:00AM';
        $end = '11:59PM';
        $interval = '+30 minutes';
        $now_str = strtotime($start);
        $end_str = strtotime($end);
        echo '<select name="schedule_time">';
        while($now_str <= $end_str){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo date('H:i A', $now_str);?>" ><?php echo date('H:i A', $now_str);?></option>
        <?php
        }
         echo '</select>';
 ?>
```